# HQL getSingleResult с подзапросом

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql

Пытаюсь написать запрос на hql, который вернет одну цифру методом getSingleResult(), все вполне сносно работало до тех пор, пока не появилась нужда в запросе отнять одно значение от другого и получить цифру. В нативном sql это делается просто:

```
select sum(a.values) - (select sum(values2) from b) from a;
```

попытылся написать то же самое на hql, вот что получилось:

```
 select sum(arrItem.itemsCount) - (select sum(itemsCount) from InvBookMuseum) 
        from InvActAcceptanceItemsMusInvAdapter  as t  INNER JOIN  t.actId as act   INNER JOIN t.arrItemId as arrItem
```

Но запрос не отрабатывает и выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
[PARSER] <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
[PARSER] right-hand operand of a binary query operator was null
```

Если же я заменяю подзапрос на простое число

> select sum(arrItem.itemsCount) - 55

то все отрабатывает как надо. 
есть возможности отнять одно число от другого на java, но для этого придется вносить нежелательные изменения в проект...

можно ли как-то обойтись без этих изменений?

спасибо!

Comment: Преобразуйте в `select sum_a-sum_b from (select sum(values) sum_a from a) x, (select sum(values2) sum_b from b) y`. *вот что получилось* Бред получился. Это ж надо было ещё догадаться - джойнить поля к таблице...

Comment: *минутка педантизма:* 55 — не простое число xD

Comment: @defaultlocale составное!!!

Comment: В документации хибернейта пишется, что допускается использование подзапросов в _select_ и в _where_, если бд это поддерживает, но, видимо, единственный допустимый вариант использования в _select_ это 


`select sum(arrItem.itemsCount) as sum_a, (select sum(itemsCount) from InvBookMuseum) as sum_b from InvActAcceptanceItemsMusInvAdapter as t LEFT JOIN t.actId as act LEFT JOIN t.arrItemId as arrItem`

после чего получается Object[] из двух объектов, которые уже, видимо, придется отнимать друг от друга вручную...